# Unable to delete a SQL Server 2012 publication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I've set up a transactional replication for two databases, let's call them A & B.

Replication for the database A worked just fine and I was able to delete it afterwards without any issues.

Replication for the database B would error out and after checking the logs I found (Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DOMAIN\someaccount', error code 0x5.).

I was going to start fresh but now I am not even able to delete it. I am trying to remove a publication from the Publisher/Distributor (both using code and via Management Studio) and getting the same error.

What concerns me is database A had no issues whatsoever, and also the fact that DOMAIN\someaccount does not appear to own any objects or be referenced within the database at all.

Please help!

Comment: @Stan, Error 0x5 means access denied.Have you check out privilege for that DB.

Comment: What is DOMAIN\someaccount?  Is it the service account?  Does it exist in AD?  I've only ever seen this once and it was down to an issue with AD.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an object owned by a user that the service account can't validate.  you can figure out what object it is, and change the owner of the object to sa.  If it's the database, run this:

```
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```